# Ruby binary left shift

Tags: ruby, binary, bit-manipulation, lsb

How to do a binary left shift in a integer value using Ruby?

---

I'm trying to do a left shift binary operation but I'm getting a strange char
instead of the move..

I think that it should perform like this: (java)

b = (b >> 2); //0011 1111
b = (b << 2); //1111 1100

I'm doing this in ruby:

```
currentRed = ChunkyPNG::Color.r(image[x,y])
currentGreen = ChunkyPNG::Color.g(image[x,y])
currentBlue = ChunkyPNG::Color.b(image[x,y])

binRed = currentRed.to_s.unpack("b*")[0]
binGreen = currentGreen.to_s.unpack("b*")[0]
binBlue = currentBlue.to_s.unpack("b*")[0]

puts "original"

puts "r #{binRed}"
puts "g #{binGreen}"
puts "b #{binBlue}"

puts "------"

binRed = binRed << 2

binGreen = binGreen << 2
binBlue = binBlue << 2


puts "new"

puts "r #{binRed}"
puts "g #{binGreen}"
puts "b #{binBlue}"
```

and getting it:

[image]

thank you in advance..

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How transform  rgb values into integer binary form? I tried transform the rgb values into binary form like this: binRed = currentRed.to_s(2)
 binGreen = currentGreen.to_s(2)
 binBlue = currentBlue.to_s(2)   but I got the same result as in the printscreen above.. because they still string..

Answer (score 4):

Your `binRed`, `binGreen`, `binBlue` are actually Strings, because `b*` unpack into *bitstrings*. For Strings, `<<` means append, so no wonder the strange character (character code 2) got printed.

I'm not familiar with ChunkyPNG, but from the [doc](http://rubydoc.info/github/wvanbergen/chunky_png/ChunkyPNG/Color) it looks like `currentRed`, `currentGreen`, `currentBlue` are already integers. You should be able to perform bit shift on them directly.

Comment: Thank you Worakam, you are right.. and yes currentRed, currentGreen and currentBlue are integers but they are rgb values, I need to transform them into binary and then perform bit shift... do you know how to do this?

Comment: You don't need to transform them to binary (because they're already binary under the hood). Just do `currentRed<<2` and it will shift 2 bits to the left... And if you want to truncate them down to 24 bits as in original, you can mask them with 0xFFFFFF. So something like `currentRed = (currentRed<<2) & 0xFFFFFF` should serve your need.

Comment: Doing this I've got: ---------
original
r 253
g 253
b 253
------
new
r 1012
g 1012
b 1012
that's correct? I need do the left shift because I'm trying to perform a last significant bit change to put my data in a png.

Comment: @Alexandre Shifting left by 2 bits is the same as multiplying by 4, so your results are correct. 253 * 4 = 1012. If you just want to alter the last bits of an integer number, you don't need to shift them at all.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, `<<` is a method. Actually most operators in Ruby are methods:

```
a = b << c
a = b + c
a = b ** c

# This is exactly the same as

a = b.<<(c)
a = b.+(c)
a = b.**(c)
```

You can even override them in your own classes to make them do whatever you want them to do. This is possibly as in Ruby everything (really everything) is an object under the hood (even classes and modules are objects, even `nil` is an object).

E.g. for a `String` the `<<` method means append.

```
a = "Hello, " << "Word"
# a == "Hello, Word"
```

But in case of a `Fixnum` the `<<` method just means shift left:

```
a = 5 << 2
# a == 20
```

So you are using the right "operator" but you need to make sure your objects are of the right class. You require integers which are of type `Fixnum` in Ruby.

And `currentRed`, `currentBlue`, and `currentGreen` are of type `Fixnum` already.